# What is the earliest place in the boot process where camera (raspistill) can be used?

Tags: boot, camera

It seems that right after local-fs.target doesn't work. Any idea what prevents it from working early in the boot process?

Comment: Does it spit out any errors (e.g. in `journalctl`) that might point towards what's missing?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't say much, except that my disableusb script (I placed the camera stuff there as a test) failed to start. Then it just hangs, it will never get to the serial console login, so I have to power off, put the card in my pc and comment out the camera line there. Lucky for me, I can access (r/w) file systems from my Windows machine, or else it would really suck :)

Comment: unclear what are you asking

Comment: You need to provide more details: the exact command that fails, the error messages (have you tried `raspistill blabla 2>&1 >error.log`?), relevant details about your boot process.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, by manually starting the script after the log in. The camera cable moved a bit and I was getting an error, and for some reason things didn't continue after that. Now it works ok.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.